# Android app crash while scrolling gridview. Have multiple Grid

Tags: android, gridview, view, android-adapter

This is the Code of my MainActivity.java.

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.gridview_layout, from, to);


    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);


    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);


    gridView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, countries, flags));
```

This is my Adapter Code.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Holder holder = new Holder();
    View rowView;

    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_layout, null);
    holder.txt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    holder.flag = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

        holder.txt.setText(result[position]);
        holder.flag.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

    rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class).putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,result[position] );
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return rowView;
}
```

}
While running the app I am getting the error like this.

`11-05 13:08:18.823 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 25984012 byte allocation with 1688216 free bytes and 1648KB until OOM"
11-05 13:08:18.830 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
11-05 13:08:18.834 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
11-05 13:08:18.835 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 25984012 byte allocation with 1688216 free bytes and 1648KB until OOM
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2477)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2384)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:787)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:403)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:760)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:411)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at com.example.vikky.basic_3.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:69)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1433)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:361)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:302)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.GridView.fillGap(GridView.java:262)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4991)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3418)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.AbsListView.startScrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3346)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.AbsListView.onInterceptTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:4259)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1960)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2407)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2407)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2407)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2407)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2369)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1719)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2752)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2330)
11-05 13:08:18.972 19321-19321/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8671)`

I searched a lot but didn't got any solution.There are some similar questions too but they don't have the right answer. kindly suggest me the best way to do it.

Comment: you are getting OOM error Out Of Memory!

declare 
        android:largeHeap="true" in manifiest file and then try.

Comment: Thanks it worked but its quite slow. Again after some time its running out of memory.  First this warning ` The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` then `"Failed to allocate a 33177612 byte allocation with 13204336 free bytes and 12MB until OOM"`

Comment: Can I use recycleradapter or any other option for it.

Comment: i guess you are loading large size images or too many images,  thats why its giving OOM.

Comment: Is there any other way to handle it.

Comment: Most of the image are are around 100kb. Total image size is only 2 Mb.

Comment: I think you need to clear your phone memory, then it's work fine

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you Replace you cod by this

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

View rowView= convertView;

ViewHolder holder = null;

if (rowView== null) {

rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_layout, null);

holder.txt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);

holder.flag = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.flag)
```

}

else {

```
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

    }

    return rowView;
}
```